# Run a test with real BLE device

Tags: android, unit-testing, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have Android application which communicates with device using BLE. I want to cover BLE logic with tests.
Is it possible to run unit tests (or maybe instrumentation tests) with real BLE device on real Android device?

Comment: Yes, but of course you need to have the BLE peripherals nearby in the specific state you want to test for... Maybe you can be a bit more specific in your question since it's very broad as it is written.

Answer (score 0):

Using only Android instrumented tests? I don't see a way of doing that.

Using external elements?
Yes, it is possible, but you need to implement your own 'framework'. I mean you need a way to control the BLE device, a library on CLI for example, this would be done outside the Android instrumentation test so you would integrate the framework to instrumented tests.